# uitableviewcell resize image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

i load data in a tableview, each row have a simple picture 500x300px that go resize to size of cell.

Is possible resize the images?

tableview.m

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:receip.image ofType:@"jpg"]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean resize them before putting them in the cell to improve performance?

You can do this with core graphics as follows:

```
//define desired size
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 100.0f);

//create drawing context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);

//draw image at new size
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];

//capture resultant image
UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Be warned though that is a computationally expensive task. You'll probably want to resize all your images in advance, possibly on a background thread, and store the resized versions in an array. You definitely **do not** want to stick the code above in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, or your table scrolling performance will be diabolical.

Answer (score 0):

If those images come from an external source (say the web). It's better to first cache the original file and then (like explained by @Nick Lockwood) resize them (remember retina displays need twice the width / height for hi-res displaying). And after that process is complete you can send a signal that the "download" is complete and carry on showing the `UITableView`

If you already have the images in your app bundle I suggest you make a thumb version of that and add it to your bundle. For better performance o'course.

Comment: In my code example the retina display is already taken care of by the 3rd parameter to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. By passing 0.0 as the scale, the context will be created with a scale of 1.0 on iPhone 3GS and 2.0 on iPhone 4 and later - you don't have to manually multiply the image size.

Comment: Good point about resizing images in the bundle though - if they are shipped with the app you should definitely just pre-generate the thumbnails.