# Determining the width/height of a UILabel within a UITableViewCell with an image

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uilabel

I’m running into a problem with determining the height of a table cell, when the table cell has a lot of text and an image. But the problem is context sensitive and depends on the type of text used. I’ll explain the issue, then give the code I’m using to format the cell and to determine cell height.
When I have an image to the left of the cell, I’m taking the cell height from the maximum height of the image versus the text. The problem is that the text height is not being computed correctly in all circumstances. Below, I have the following text in the bottom cell:

“P 154 Vietnamese home cooking: very good!! Blenderized the spices into a paste-- worked well; used remaining sauce on zuchinni to grill; worked well; thick pork chops; cooked at between 450 and 525 for 35 minutes”.

The table view is scrolled all the way to the bottom. As you can see the bottom portion of the text is not present (“cooked at between 450 and 525 for 35 minutes”). What is actually going on is that the text width is not being determined correctly. Below, the text width is being computed as cell.textLabel.bounds.size.width: 234 pixels. Based on this, the height of the text is incorrectly computed.
[image: Simulator screen grab showing incomplete text]

However, if I press on the accessory button (“>”) and descend into my next view, then return from that view (using a “back” button with a navigation controller), I typically get the following changed table display (but sometimes I still get the view above without the remaining text):
[image: Simulator screen grab showing complete text]

In this case, the second time the table view is displayed, the width of the text is computed as cell.textLabel.bounds.size.width: 163 pixels.
The difference between the two text widths (234 - 163 = 71 pixels). The image width is 100 pixels. 
The situation is, unfortunately, even more complicated than this:
1) If I have no image in the cell, I have no problem with determining the width of the text.
2) If I use just a series of simple lines of text such as a consecutive series of numbers/letters with a carriage return after each character, the width is correctly determined. For example, if the text in the cell is:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
A
B
C

3) If there are cells following (below) the cell with the large amount of full-line text (not the text consisting of characters followed by carriage returns), then I never get the cell width computed correctly (and hence the height is never computed correctly).

**What Have I Tried?**

Within cellForRowAtIndexPath, I have tried:
        cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
as advised by [Dynamic UILabel Heights/Widths in UITableViewCell in all Orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239040/dynamic-uilabel-heights-widths-in-uitableviewcell-in-all-orientations) but this didn’t change the situation.

I also tried putting in the suggestion from [Calculating multiline text height for UILabel/UITableViewCell: different results when calculating vs actual drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136051/calculating-multiline-text-height-for-uilabel-uitableviewcell-different-results) into cellForRowAtIndexPath that forces a new width for the text label, but this didn’t work.

**A Hack That Worked**

What *did* work was to force the text label width to be the correct width within heightForRowAtIndexPath. However, this is certainly a hack. I’d like a better solution. Ideas?

**Code**

In the code that follows BUG74 is the issue I've been describing here.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129502/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-uitableviewcell-without-a-custom-cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellCommentList";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"CommentList.cellForRowAtIndexPath: nil case");
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        IF_IOS6_OR_GREATER(
            cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        );
        IF_LESS_THAN_IOS6(
            cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        );

        // To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    }

    NSDictionary *menuItemCommentDictionary =
    [Globals GetIthMenuItemComment: indexPath.row forMenuItem: menuItemName andRestaurant: restaurantName];

    //NSDate *commentDate = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];

    if (CommentListDebug) NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    UIImage *theIcon;
    NSString *imageFileName = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:COMMENT_KEY_IMAGE_FILENAME];

    if (imageFileName) {
        // Scaling images in table view cells
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046573/uitableviewcell-resize-image

#define DEFAULT_TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT 44
#define IMAGE_WIDTH_IN_TABLE_CELL 100
        /* I'm going to give images a constant width and adjust
         the height of the table cell according to their height.
         */
        theIcon = [PersistentStorage retrieveIconFromFile:imageFileName];

        if (CommentListDebug) NSLog(@"icon: %@", theIcon);

        //NSNumber *iconHeight  = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:@"imageIconHeight"];

        //if (CommentListDebug) NSLog(@"iconHeight: %d", [iconHeight intValue]);

        cell.imageView.image = theIcon;
    } else {
        if (CommentListDebug) NSLog(@"No image file name");
        cell.imageView.image = nil; // Otherwise, if using old cell, uses old icon image
    }

    NSString *cellText = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:@"menuItemComment"];

    // 1/5/13; Bug# 62; only if there is no icon/image and no text
    // should we mark as empty.
    if ((! imageFileName) && ((nil == cellText) || ([cellText length] == 0))) {
        cellText = EMPTY_TEXT; // temporary empty text
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;

    // BUG74: 1/29/13;
    // We are not having problems with the text width when there
    // is no icon, so only do this when there is an icon
    // NOTE: This does *not* work; for some reason, the frame.size.width
    // is not retained in the call to heightForRowAtIndexPath.
    if (imageFileName) {
        CGRect labelFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
        labelFrame.size.width = 287 - 27 - theIcon.size.width;
        NSLog(@"CommentList.cellForRowAtIndexPath: labelFrame.size.width: %d", (int) labelFrame.size.width);
        cell.textLabel.frame = labelFrame;
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)thisTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *menuItemCommentDictionary =
        [Globals GetIthMenuItemComment: indexPath.row forMenuItem: menuItemName andRestaurant: restaurantName];
    NSString *cellText  = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:@"menuItemComment"];

    // 1/5/13; Bug# 62; I'm going to allow empty comments in the case
    // where there is no picture and no text. This is to allow a user
    // to have a smiley rating only but no picture and no text.
    // The issue here is that with no text, the height of the row
    // is too small, and looks odd. And it's hard to select that row to
    // delete because it's not very tall.
    // My fix for this it to add some temporary empty text. I've used
    // non-white space text, because I still get the issue if I use
    // white space. If I add the display of smiley's in the comment
    // list then this issue should go away).
    // For some reason the cellText does not seem to be nil when there
    // is no text.
    if ((nil == cellText) || ([cellText length] == 0)) {
        cellText = EMPTY_TEXT; // temporary empty text
    }

    //NSDate *commentDate = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:@"date"];

    NSString *imageFileName = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:COMMENT_KEY_IMAGE_FILENAME];

    // If I directly retrieve the icon from the file and display it
    // that way, I get a mess! The image is much too large!!
    UIImage *theIcon = nil;
    if (imageFileName) {
        theIcon = [PersistentStorage retrieveIconFromFile:imageFileName];
    }

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

    // Some of the following code modified from:
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947970/dynamic-calculation-of-uilabel-width-in-uitableviewcell
    // Find the cell for this index path
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:thisTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //CGFloat cellHeight = cell.frame.size.height;

    // Calculate text size after forcing a layout    
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    //CGSize textSize = [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];

    NSLog(@"CommentList.heightForRowAtIndexPath: cell.textLabel.bounds.size.width: %d", (int) cell.textLabel.bounds.size.width);

    // In my tests, bounds.size.width is the same as frame.size.width
    NSLog(@"CommentList.heightForRowAtIndexPath: cell.textLabel.frame.size.width: %d", (int) cell.textLabel.frame.size.width);

    // cell.contentView.bounds.size.width gives the full width of the
    // cell contents, which was 287 pixels when I tested it
    if (CommentListDebug) NSLog(@"CommentList.heightForRowAtIndexPath: cell.contentView.bounds.size.width: %d", (int) cell.contentView.bounds.size.width);

    // parameters to CGSizeMake are: width, height
    // the width parameter here is supposed to be the text width;

    CGSize constraintSize;

    if (theIcon) {
        // Start hack for BUG74; 1/29/13
        // The number 27 just works; Is it the width of the
        // accessory button within the cell?
        // cell.contentView.bounds.size.width was 287 when I checked.
        int textWidth = cell.contentView.bounds.size.width - 27 - theIcon.size.width;
        constraintSize = CGSizeMake(textWidth, MAXFLOAT);
        // End hack for BUG74; 1/29/13
    } else {
        constraintSize = CGSizeMake(cell.textLabel.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
    }

    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode];

    //NSNumber *iconHeight  = [menuItemCommentDictionary objectForKey:@"imageIconHeight"];

#define LABEL_HEIGHT_EXTRA 20
#define ICON_HEIGHT_EXTRA 10

    int textHeight = labelSize.height + LABEL_HEIGHT_EXTRA;

    if (theIcon) {
    //if ([iconHeight intValue] > 0) {
        // Add 10 EXTRA here to give some white space between icons;
        // with no white space, it can be hard to tell where one icon
        // starts and where another ends, particularly because
        // icons have variable height.
        int iconHeight = ((int) theIcon.size.height) + ICON_HEIGHT_EXTRA;

        /* if (CommentListDebug) */NSLog(@"CommentList.heightForRowAtIndexPath: icon height: %d; icon width: %d", (int) theIcon.size.height, (int) theIcon.size.width);

        // BUG74: 1/28/13; If the text height is taller than the image 
        // height use the text height as the cell height.
        NSLog(@"CommentList.heightForRowAtIndexPath: iconHeight= %d, textHeight= %d", iconHeight, textHeight);

        if (iconHeight >= textHeight) return iconHeight;
        return textHeight;

        //return [iconHeight intValue] + 10;
    } else {
        // No image; use label size for height.
        return textHeight;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So please correct me if I am mistaken but if you were able to increase the size of the cell (like the bottom picture) then everything would work how you wanted it to? If that is the case you can override:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

This would allow you to specify how tall you want the cells. This way you could set them and prevent them from cutting of the text on the bottom (like the first picture).

Comment: I have implemented this method. Please see my code above. Thanks.